# checking if email and confirm email fields are the same using php

Tags: php

I would like to confirm that the email field and confirm email field match each other in my html form before submitting the form to the database, i have done the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php

if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$_SESSION['error'][] = "Invalid email address";
}
    
if ($_POST['email'] != $_POST['confirmemail']) {
$_SESSION['error'][] = "Email addresses do not match";
}
          
else {
```

this is followed by the script to submit the form to the database which works fine. Any suggestions would be welcome, many thanks

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['email'], $_POST['confirmemail'], $_POST['email'] == $_POST['confirmemail']);` – results in what?

Answer (score 0):

There might be whitespace issue causing your comparison to fail. try trimming your inputs before comparison.

```
$email = trim( $_POST['email'] );
$confirmEmail = trim( $_POST['confirmemail'] );

if ($emsil != $confirmEmail ) {
   $_SESSION['error'][] = "Email addresses do not match";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Just saying does not work, wont help a thing. Did u try debugging whats going wrong, print/vardump whatever inputs u r getting